# 'long long long' is too long for GCC using log4cpp

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, long-integer, log4cpp

I am developing a QT application where I use the logging library log4cpp.
But now, where the headerfiles of log4pp are included, I get this compiling error:
**'long long long' is too long for GCC**

When I go to the source of this error, the headerfile stdint.h is opened at this line:

**__MINGW_EXTENSION typedef long long  int64_t;**

Can anybody tell me how to handle this?

Comment: One possibility is a rogue `#define int64_t long` (or `long long`) in some evil header. If you find such a thing, destroy that header immediately.

Comment: `typedef long long long long` would be a bit too long.

Comment: @Yakk: Indeed, but it will cause this error (and another one): http://ideone.com/hplyg2

Comment: I've searched for #define int64_t long, but I couldn't find it in one of those headers :/

Answer (score 2):

Okay, solved it, I just needet to include the stdint.h at first oO